# Difference between long polling and setTimeout

Tags: settimeout, long-polling, polling

What is the differnce between Long-Polling and setTimeout
I found this for long polling but it could not make any difference from setTimeout.

```
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);

    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what your code does is normal polling.

Long polling keeps the client request open until new data is there to be send to the client. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) describes it at best:

> With long polling, the client requests information from the server
>   exactly as in normal polling, except it issues its HTTP/S requests
>   (polls) at a much slower frequency. If the server does not have any
>   information available for the client when the poll is received,
>   instead of sending an empty response, the server holds the request
>   open and waits for response information to become available. Once it
>   does, the server immediately sends an HTTP/S response to the client,
>   completing the open HTTP/S Request. In this way the usual response
>   latency (the time between when the information first becomes available
>   and the next client request) otherwise associated with polling clients
>   is eliminated.